# Summing different columns with different conditions in Sql

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

Can someone help please.
I have a table with a

```
player_home,
player_away,
team_home,
team_away,
score_home,
score_away

player_home always has team_home and score_home.
player_away always has team_away and score_away
```

Problem is on one row the player 'Rob' can be player_home and the next row he is player_away.

What I wanna get out of this table is..
How many times did 'Rob' win a game?
How can I query this? 
I appreciate the help!
:-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `union all` to combine 2 queries

```
select sum(case when player_home = 'rob' and score_home > score_away) 
                then 1 
                else 0 
           end) as wins
from your_table
union all 
select sum(case when player_away = 'rob' and score_home < score_away) 
                then 1 
                else 0 
           end)
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select `1` from all rows where your condition "Rob has won" holds, and `0` for all others rows, and aggregate with `sum`:

```
select sum(case 
             when player_home = 'Rob' and score_home > score_away or 
                  player_away = 'Rob' and score_away > score_home 
               then 1 
             else 0 end) rob_wins 
from scores;
```

Note: I assume 'Rob' uniquely identifies a player here, i.e. there are no two players named Rob, playing in different teams for example ;-)

HTH!